# jQuery Mobile - How to Check if the Browser supports jQuery Mobile events

Tags: jquery, events, mobile

I am currently using the jQuery Mobile "pagebeforecreate" page initialization event to load content into my html page. The jQuery Mobile events are discussed here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/api/events.html. After the content is loaded synchronously and appended to the body jQuery Mobile formats the page.

Here is my code which works in browsers that support jQuery Mobile:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery Mobile Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $('body').live('pagebeforecreate',function(event){

        var ajaxContent = "";

        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: "GET",
            url: "test.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) { 

                $(xml).find('item').each(function()
                {
                    ajaxContent += '<li><a href="'+$(this).find('link').text()+'">'+$(this).find('title').text()+'</a></li>';
                });
                //alert(ajaxContent);
                $('#menu').append(ajaxContent);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>You must have JavaScript enabled to view the content on this website.</noscript>
<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>jQuery Mobile</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">

        <ul data-role="listview" id="menu">

            <li><a href="#">Static</a></li>

        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu>
<item>
<title>Awesome Link from XML 1</title>
<link>http://www.google.com</link>
</item>
<item>
<title>Awesome Link from XML 2</title>
<link>http://www.gmail.com</link>
</item>
</menu>
```

How can I detect if the browser supports the "pagebeforecreate" jQuery Mobile event? Or is there a way to detect if this event was executed? If this event is never executed I need to load the XML with another function. Even though IE 8 does not support jQuery Mobile I would still like it to process the XML file and display the links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/

> jQuery Mobile is working to support
>   all A grade browsers. This means that
>   we will be actively testing against
>   those browsers and ensuring that they
>   work as best as they possibly can. The
>   browsers will receive the full jQuery
>   Mobile CSS and JavaScript (although
>   the ultimate layout may be a
>   gracefully degraded version of the
>   full capabilities, depending upon the
>   browser).

To check if a browser is defined as grade A, you can call

```
$.mobile.gradeA()
```

I don't have IE to check what that gives for this, but you can give it a try

Comment: Thanks! That works great. I have tested "if (!$.mobile.gradeA())" and it works in IE 8. Is there any documentation on the "$.mobile.gradeA()" event? I didn't see anything about it on the jQuery Mobile website.

Comment: I should flag you by giving a link throwing back to this page