# how to debug javascript in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, jquery-mobile

HI I have a mobile version of a web app that doesn't work only on a blackberry. Everything works on IOS and Droids(well not exactly everything, but it is *usable*)

Basically, my problem is this: I can't click on any link or button. Actually there is only one link that works and it is a plain html link that leads to another page. The others im trying are buttons and links that have javascript in them to show a different partial/page

One of the results I have found is that a bb's js might be turned off. TO check, i added an alert on page load ang voila! it works..but only the alert. clicking the buttons many times wont even take me nywehere. it just ignores my clicks

How do i debug this? Is there any clue as to what my problem actually is(so i can google)? I am using the jquery mobile framework and have tested the demo using the BB so im pretty sure it was not their fault, but rather mine

Comment: is the BB device supported? http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/

Comment: hmm it says it is C-grade(i am using a curve) BUT, C-grade denotes, no JS. I have actually tested and seen my JS alerts when loading the page and clicking the button so Im pretty sure js works...although ajax might be another matter

Comment: If you can, try to test on another device or emulator. You can also do a test to see if the device is supported. If it's not you could throw an alert to the end user or something saying this device is not supported: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Comment: ive actually tried going to the jquery mobile page using the blackberry and it works. so i kinda had the impression that it was 'supported' and thus the problem was with how it was coded. (unless jquery mobile was coded without ajax in mind)

Comment: okay i just tested using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833281/jquery-mobile-how-to-check-if-the-browser-supports-jquery-mobile-events/4835439#4835439...$.mobile.gradeA() returns true! now im even more confused

Comment: maybe edit your question and add/post some code?

Comment: I'm having the same issues with BB OS 6 and 7 simulators. I've upgraded to jqm 1.1.1 and everything works on droid and ios. no jqm buttons or links respond to clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Debugging/Logging

- http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH149375

Or using a Simulator might be the way to go

- http://us.blackberry.com/developers/resources/simulators.jsp
- http://www.blackberry.com/developers/downloads/simulators/